# What does accuracy means in PCIe local clock?

Tags: pci, pci-e, pci-bus

In the receiver side of the physical layer's logic block, the local clock is accurate to +/- 300 ppm. Can anyone explain about this in details please?!

Comment: Dear @Roronoa_Zoro welcome to SO. Please note that it is one thing to ask precisely about "accuracy" in the title of your post and a totally different thing to ask to explain in details your first sentence. I decided to answer the title question but I think you'll get downvoted because your second question is not precise enough. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCIe local clock is specified at 100MHz. In real life you never get an oscillator that is always perfectly at this frequency. The accuracy figure of 300ppm means that the "real" clock signal may vary between 99.97MHz an 100.03MHz but not beyond.